# Mysql subtract from epoch

Tags: mysql

I have a field named LAST_UPDATE which contains epoch time stored as int(4) unsigned.  I'd like to select all fields which are less than 1 minute from the epoch time stored.

For example 1549568865 minus 60:

```
SELECT * FROM ips WHERE LAST_UPDATE < LAST_UPDATE - 60
```

I've tried different iterations of this command but to no avail.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: you have error?   show error message .. wrong result .. add tables schema   a data sample yiour actual result and the expected  result

Comment: There's no error, it simply displays all the fields instead of those which are less than epoch - 60 seconds.

Comment: First attempt, to get the epoch. You can change this to meet your criteria or interval.
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(1225540800), INTERVAL - 1 SECOND))

Comment: are you sure the data type is int ??

Comment: Yes, from describe table:  LAST_UPDATE | int(4) unsigned

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get results by doing:

SELECT * FROM ips WHERE LAST_UPDATE > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60

Thank you all who responded.